# How to add a Sliding Drawer in my mobile messaging Android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I'm new in Android development. My developer is asking huge money Rs. 40,000 to add a "Sliding Drawer" in my mobile messaging app, which is still developed by himself.

I've a shoe-string budget. Can you pls help me to add one "sliding Drawer" in my app. I'm very much fascinated by the "Sliding Drawer" of gaana app.

Comment: Do you mean a "Navigation Drawer" at the left of your screen?

Comment: Ya, at the left of the screen with sliding to the right by tapping the 'action overflow.'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official guide on how to implement a navigation drawer:

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Answer (score 1):

> **Creating a Sliding Drawer**

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Title of the action bar
    String mTitle="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = (String) getTitle();

        // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){

                /** Called when drawer is closed */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
        };

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.drawer_list_item ,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers)
        );

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view,
                int position,
                long id) {

                    // Getting an array of rivers
                    String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

                    //Currently selected river
                    mTitle = rivers[position];

                    // Creating a fragment object
                    RiverFragment rFragment = new RiverFragment();

                    // Creating a Bundle object
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();

                    // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
                    data.putInt("position", position);

                    // Setting the position to the fragment
                    rFragment.setArguments(data);

                    // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                    // Creating a fragment transaction
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

                    // Committing the transaction
                    ft.commit();

                    // Closing the drawer
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    /** Handling the touch event of app icon */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

**For Step by Step Guide to implement a navigation drawer check these tutorials:**

1. http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html
2. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
3. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/